# Is SplFixedArray implemented in C/C++ under the hood?

Tags: php, c++, c, arrays, spl

I'm not very familiar with the source code behind the entity we know as PHP, so I don't know whether the SPL library in general and SplFixedArray in particular are implemented in C/C++. Would anyone have the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you´ll find a link to a "spl_fixedarray.c" file:
http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=tree;f=ext/spl
=> It is C